# Eliminar instancias en Java

Tags: java, poo, object, objeto

tengo un problema con un método cuya función es eliminar una instancia. He buscado cómo hacerlo pero no me sirve ninguna respuesta; la que más se acerca es igualar a null el objeto que quiero eliminar pero no me termina de funcionar como deseo. Dejo el código aquí, gracias.

```
/**
 * El cazador mata un personaje del que sospeche.
 * @param muerto es el personaje que muere
 */
public void matar(Personaje muerto) {
    //si el personaje es una instancia de la clase Lobo
    if(muerto instanceof Lobo) {
        System.out.println("El lobo ha muerto.");
        //igualar a null es similar a eliminar una instancia.
        muerto = null;
    }
}
```

Mi objetivo es que a la hora de ejecutar este método en el main, la instancia del objeto Lobo sea eliminada. Aquí va el código del main:

```
public static void main(String args []){
//los parametros son nombre de los personajes e indicar si vive con un booleano
Cazador c = new Cazador("cazador",true);
Lobo l = new Lobo("lobo", true);
//despues del metodo matar es cuando la instancia 'l' debe ser borrada
c.matar(l);
```

Comment: ¿Podrías aclarar un poco cuál es el comportamiento deseado? Dices: *"no me termina de funcionar como deseo"*. ¿Qué deseas que haga?. Si lo que deseas es liberar el espacio de memoria al momento de *"matar"* al personaje, entonces puedes llamar al método `gc()` de `System`. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras deseo eliminar la instancia del objeto Personaje. Voy a dejar el ejemplo de cómo querría ejecutarlo en main.

Comment: @unanobot eso que hiciste de colocar `RESUELTA` no es válido en este plataforma, basta con que aceptes y califiques la respuesta que te soluciono el problema para entender que ya fue resuelta la duda

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cuando en java se "crea" una instancia hay un espacio de memoria que se reserva para esa instancia y ese epacio de memoria es asignado a una variable.

Una vez que hay una variable mirando ese espacio de memoria pueden crearse mas variables y hacerlas mirar a ese mismo espacio de memoria (distintas variables pueden hacer refrencia a la misma instancia).

"Destruir" la instancia (como contraposición de crearla) significa liberar ese espacio de memoria. En java esto ocurre cuando ya no hay variables mirando el espacio reservado para la instancia.

La forma de hacer que una variable ya no referencie una instancia, es seteándola a null (o a otra instancia diferente).

Cuando ya no hay variables mirando la instancia la jvm puede disponer de esa memoria a través del Garbage Collector.

Ni el programador ni el usuario tienen control sobre cuando correrá el Garbage Collector, esto lo maneja internamente la jvm.

Answer (score 0):

**l** apunta a un objeto del tipo Lobo, entonces tienes que hacer que **l** apunte a **null**, luego de esto  **l** dejará de apuntar a ese objeto de tipo lobo y este se borrará